# Select specific field in MongoDB using ruby then pass the value to a variable

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm working on a script that will return value in a specific field and exclude other fields i tried these codes:

```
name = 'bierc'
puts collection.find({"name"=> name},{:fields => { "_id" => 0}}).to_a
```

and

```
name = 'bierc'
collection.find("name" => name,"_id" => 0).each{|row| puts row.inspect}
```

These two returns

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('55f0d965fcd4fe1c659cf472'), "name"=>"bierc", "song"=>"testsong"}
```

I want to select ***name*** only and exclude the ***song*** and especially the ***_id*** then will work on to pass the value of ***name*** field to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is not `fields` but [`projection`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method).  You do need `_id => 0` but then `1` for any field or fields you *do* want to select should exclude the others.

```
collection.find("name" => name, projection: => { "_id" => 0, "name" => 1}})
```

Comment: Thanks it works well! by the way i'm still figuring out on how to pass it to ruby variable. if i do result = collection.find({"name"=> name}, :projection => {"_id" => 0, "name" => 1 }).to_a
  puts result it will display {"name"=>"bierc"} i want to display the bierc only

Comment: I think just `.to_a["name"]`